# How to configure RestAssured LogConfig to write request and response to a text file

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I am totally newbie to RestAssured. I like to write the request and response to text file. I do not want to repeat code in each and every test to extract and write Request and Response but instead I like to configure RestAssuredConfig in a setup method to redirect the request and response to text file.

Can someone please help me understand what I am missing in my code? I am trying to configure LogConfig to write request and response to StringWriter so that I can use it to write to a required file?

I tried several examples from google but none helped.

Please note, below example is a proto type in which I am temporarily doing sysout and once the code works I can write it to text file.

//This is a sample code from where I am calling the configure log method //configureRequestLogging

```
RequestSpecification request = given();
RequestSpecification logRequest = configureRequestLogging(request);
```

//This method is expected to SOP the request and response. But I am always getting void

```
private static RequestSpecification configureRequestLogging(RequestSpecification request) {
    RequestSpecification requestSpec;
    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    PrintStream captor = new PrintStream(new WriterOutputStream(writer), true);
    requestSpec = request.config(RestAssuredConfig.config().logConfig(LogConfig.logConfig().defaultStream(captor)))
    .log().all();

    System.out.println(writer.toString());

    return requestSpec;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new logging filter (interface `Filter`) if you want to have file output separated from console output (e.g. provide more details)
There you can specify print stream

```
@Override
public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec, FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
    RequestPrinter.print(requestSpec, requestSpec.getMethod(), requestSpec.getUri(), LogDetail.ALL, new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("example.txt", true)), true);
    return ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
}
```

Also you just could add built-in RequestLoggingFilter with required print stream.